# How to get back to normal mode when using vim keybindings in Firefox code/style editor?

Tags: firefox, vim

I'm trying to use vim keybindings for the code/style editor in Firefox Developer Edition. I can type "i" to get into insert mode, but how can I get back to normal mode? The escape key toggles the console pane but doesn't get me back to normal mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two do the same as `ESC` in vim, so one (or both) might work for you:

- `Ctrl + [`
- `ctrl + c`

...the latter of which I prefer to use over ESC. Hopefully your keybindings include them.

Comment: Just so you know, using `Ctrl-C` to leave insert mode has drawbacks. For one, it doesn't trigger the `InsertLeave` autocmd event.